# Android Project in Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin

I'm doing a mobile app project for android using Xamarin Forms. I am displaying images using a grid. The images appear okay but when I apply margins or padding to the top the images shrink. Does anyone know whats causing this?

Comment: Can add code snippets for the same. That might be helpful.

Comment: I am sure we would be just speculating if you do not add some code

Comment: We can help you better if you provide some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use the image attribute: `Aspect="AspectFit"` to force the image to properly fit the reserved space.